# Comparing time in text format in psql 12

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

```
SELECT *
FROM   lighting
WHERE  cast("time" as timestamp) BETWEEN '23:55:00'::timestamp
AND now();
```

But I get the error as follows:

`ERROR:  column "23:55:00::timestamp" does not exist LINE 3: WHERE  cast("time" as timestamp) BETWEEN "23:55:00::timestam...`

My "time" column is as follows in a text format

```
05:50:53
06:58:38
07:30:42
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query and the error message are not consistent. The query has `'23:55:00'::timestamp`, while the error shows `"23:55:00::timestamp"`.

Comment: It seems your field `"time"` is having values as `time` which can not be converted into `timestamp`, if you want to compare the time only then you can use `time` in place of `timestamp` and 'current_time' in place of `now()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your field "time" is having values as `time` which can not be converted into `timestamp`.

So try this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   lighting
WHERE  cast("time" as time) BETWEEN '23:55:00'::time
AND current_time;
```